# SAP Data Services Management Console: Unable to connect to any repository. Please verify repository connection information from Administrator

Tags: business-objects

After our Server OS upgrade, when I access Data Services Management Console.
other icons became disabled and this error prompts.

[image]

Anyone have idea?

Tried accessing Administrator but this error also prompts

> Unable to connect to any repository. Please verify repository connection information from Administrator

And when I try opening the Administrator
this prompts.

[image]

Its weird since our Jobs still runs even if we cannot access it.